# Error installing GMLib 1.2.4

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, gmlib

I got that error trying to reinstall GMLib (GMLib_DXE5_FMX.bpl):

> [dcc32 Fatal Error] F2039 Could not create output file
>   'C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\Bpl\GMLib_DXE5.bpl'
>
> [dcc32 Fatal Error] GMLib_DXE5_FMX.dpk(36): E2202 Required package
>   'GMLib_DXE5' not found

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: uninstall gmlib and delete dcu and bpl files. After, reinstall it. However, FMX package is not necessary to install it because at this moment GMLib only work with VCL.TWebBrowser

Comment: I'd unninstalled gmlib, deleted the BPL Files. Tryied to reinstall gmlib, again i got that error when i compiled GMLib_DXE5_FMX.bpl.
Then i just ignored this. and keep following the steps from Install.txt.

Now i got another error when I tryied to compile my old project without modify anything.

>[DCC Fatal Error] F1026 File not found: 'Unit1.pas'

Now, any project that i try to Run, i got some error message...

Any idea what could that be?

Comment: Also I did try to change platform to windows32 bit, and got another errors.
>[dcc32 Error] E1026 File not found: 'FMX.Filter.res'
>[dcc32 Error] E1026 File not found: 'FMX.Controls.Win.res'

Comment: have you added the install dir into the search path of your XE5?

Comment: Yes.
Well I'm giving up this, I think i'm going to develop a HTML + JS page, and then call it from my mobile app (delphi).
What do you guys think about it. I think i'll lose too much time doing that...